# Dinamically creating Chart.js dataset not working with data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have got some problem while trying to dynamically create a dataset for myChart, I am using this code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
                        fullWidth: true,
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            //datasets: [{
                                //data: answers,
                                //backgroundColor: BackGroudColorRandom
                            //}]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true,
                                        suggestedMin: 0,
                                        autoSkip: false,
                                        maxRotation: 90,
                                        minRotation: 90
                                    }
                                }]
                            },
                            xAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    autoSkip: false,
                                    maxRotation: 90,
                                    minRotation: 90
                                }
                            }],
                            legend: {
                                onClick: false,
                                display: true,
                                position: 'bottom',
                                labels: {
                                    //generateLabels: function (myChart) {
                                    //    var labels = myChart.data.labels;
                                    //    var dataset = myChart.data.datasets[0];
                                    //    var legend = labels.map(function (label, index) {
                                    //        return {
                                    //            datasetIndex: 0,
                                    //            fillStyle: dataset.backgroundColor && dataset.backgroundColor[index],
                                    //            strokeStyle: dataset.borderColor && dataset.borderColor[index],
                                    //            lineWidth: dataset.borderWidth,
                                    //            text: label
                                    //        }
                                    //    });
                                    //    return legend;
                                    //},
                                    //fontColor: "#000080",
                                },
                                maxRotation: 90,
                                minRotation: 90
                            },

                        }
                    });

                    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                        var newDataset = {
                            label: labels[i],
                            backgroundColor: BackGroudColorRandom[i],
                            data: [asnwers[i]]
                        };
                        myChart.config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
                    }

                    myChart.update();
```

But the chart is showing all the data values grouped in just one column, while the others are empty. If i try in this way "data: answers[i]" removing the "[]" I just get all blank values (while the legend labels still work).

I am populating my dataset with value from backend retrieved inside my DB

```
for (var j = 0; j < result[1].MaxAnswers; j++) {
                                    if (result[0][i].ListaQuestions[k].ListAnswers[j] != undefined) {
                                        var CountAnswers = result[0][i].ListaQuestions[k].ListAnswers[j].CountAnswers;
                                        value += CountAnswers;
                                        if (j == result[0][i].ListaQuestions[k].ListAnswers.length - 1) {
                                            asnwers[k] = answers[k] + number;
                                            number= 0;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

it's just an array containing 9 values ex at 0 index I have 10, 1 index 20 etc..

I have tried using just onedataset passing all the data and it works, but then when I want hide just one column on legend click it doesn't work it hides all the whole dataset instead the only clicked label.

In debugging I can see my chart has 9 datasets with the correct label, color and data just it won't show up my data.

Thank you

Comment: share your dataset which you are passing in the chart

Comment: Yeah, show us where you're getting 'asnwers' from and what it looks like.  Think you may have it misspelled as in the commented out section you have it as 'answers'